# How can I copy my Gmail filters to my local email client?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, gmail, email-filter

I user Thunderbird on my Mac while I'm at work and when I'm home I use Outlook 2007 on my PC. Is there a way I can copy my Gmail filters into either client in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up TBird with Gmail IMAP (not POP) then it will import your filters and folders automatically.

edit: That was a typo! as should have been AND.

Comment: Filters aren't folders or tags.

Comment: @random - I am aware.  The IMAP will add the folders as needed, and apply any filters server-side.  The AS was a typo and has been fixed.